# Query table depending on id matching comma separated field

Tags: mysql

I have a table on my database that lists different sections to show. We only want to show the sections if the user ID is inside a column of the database called 'userAccess' which will have a comma seperated list of the users who can see it.

Example row

```
id    section   userAccess
1     editNews  1,13,15
```

So how can I query that out and say something like

```
SELECT `section` WHERE '$userID' is in `userAccess`
```

I tried LIKE %, but obviously that will return all 3 users if I do LIKE %1%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `section` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('$userID', `userAccess`) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider moving to a groups based permissioning structure, then have a GroupAccess table, with an FK to your section and the group ID. Users would be assigned to a Group in a UserGroup link table. This provides you with a lot of flexibility (but more complexity).

Or failing that, simply have

```
id section  userAccess
1  editNews 1
2  editNews 13
3  editNews 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT `section`
FROM t
WHERE concat(',', '$userID', ',') like concat(',', `userAccess`, ',')
```

In other words, you can use like if you put the separator around the two strings.  I offer this because it is more similar to the solution you tried and you can use the same approach in other databases.